# Wordpress subdomain and multisite

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, subdomain

Ok, here is the situation i can´t solve:

I have a WP multisite running on a server with 3 domains and 3 sites, and in that server i also have a subdomain running it´s own WP.

So, let´s say i have this MU sites:

```
site_1.com
site_2.com
site_3.com
```

And also i have this subdomain:

```
blog.site_1.com
```

The thing is if i go to this url: "site_2.com/blog" it show me the page using a 404 template with the subdomain theme style. Yeah!!

So, trying to access "site_2.com/blog", give me 404 using a theme that is in use on a subdomain named "blog" that is live over: blog.site_1.com.

My MU htaccess has this:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?files/(.+) wp-includes/ms-files.php?file=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule  ^[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule  ^[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/(.*\.php)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog.site_1.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.blog.site_1.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://site_1.com [R=301,L]
```

Last 3 lines are obviusly required in order to have a diferent WP instalation running on that subdomain that is actualy the "blog" folder on my public_html.

Also that "blog/" folder (where is installed the site under blog.site_1.com) has this default wp htaccess code:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Maybe thats the problem, i have for one part a multisite running with 3 domains maping into the same server, but also on another part a subdomain running it´s own wp instalation and, badly, in this case i builded a page named "blog" that conflict with the "blog" folder that is actualy another site ?¿?¿?¿ jejej, it´s crazy, and at this point this is personal :) i need to know why i can´t make this working ok.

Any idea on how i can solve this thing? Thanks

Comment: The faulty rule is not in this piece of htaccess. There must be another htaccess somewhere, maybe in the site_2 root directory. If you reply to this message, make sure to start with `@zx81` if you want me to see it.

Comment: zx81, thanks, please take a look i edited my question, is not a real "redirection", it keeps on the URL its supposed to be, but using the theme style that uses subdomain site, that is actualy another wp instalation...